# How to setTimeout in Java Elasticsearch

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, timeout, settimeout

Hello Elasticsearch friends
I wanted to set a timeout when I'm searching. So put the setTimeout in SearchRequestBuilder to 10s. But every time I become a PARSE FAILURE with my Query. I don't understand why.

Here is my SearchController with the setTimeout:

```
@RestController
public class SearchController {
@Autowired
@Named("es")
private Node node;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/{query}")
public List<Hit> search(@PathVariable("query") String query){
    Client client = node.client();
    List<Hit> esData = new ArrayList<Hit>();

    SearchRequestBuilder request1 = client.prepareSearch("orange11").setTimeout("10s").setQuery(query);

    SearchResponse response1 = request1.execute().actionGet();

    System.out.println("Hits: "+response1.getHits());

    for(SearchHit hit : response1.getHits()){

        Hit hitDto = new Hit(hit.getSource());
        Map<String, HighlightField> highlightFields = hit.getHighlightFields();
        for(String s : highlightFields.keySet()){
            List<String> fragmentsDto = new ArrayList<>();
            Text [] fragments = highlightFields.get(s).fragments();
            for (Text fragment : fragments){
                fragmentsDto.add(fragment.toString());
            }
            hitDto.addField("_all", fragmentsDto);
        }
        esData.add(hitDto);
    }
    return esData;
}


}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[67Vq8cvCSVm9GROgOY-ifQ][orange11][0]: SearchParseException[[orange11][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"timeout":10000,"query_binary":"eyJzaXplIiA6IDEwLCAiZnJvbSIgOiAwLCAicXVlcnkiIDogeyAibWF0Y2giIDogeyAiX2FsbCIgOiB7InF1ZXJ5IiA6ICJkb2xvcmUifX19LCAiaGlnaGxpZ2h0IiA6IHsiZmllbGRzIiA6IHsgIioiIDoge319LCAicmVxdWlyZV9maWVsZF9tYXRjaCIgOiBmYWxzZX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[orange11] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[67Vq8cvCSVm9GROgOY-ifQ][orange11][1]: SearchParseException[[orange11][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"timeout":10000,"query_binary":"eyJzaXplIiA6IDEwLCAiZnJvbSIgOiAwLCAicXVlcnkiIDogeyAibWF0Y2giIDogeyAiX2FsbCIgOiB7InF1ZXJ5IiA6ICJkb2xvcmUifX19LCAiaGlnaGxpZ2h0IiA6IHsiZmllbGRzIiA6IHsgIioiIDoge319LCAicmVxdWlyZV9maWVsZF9tYXRjaCIgOiBmYWxzZX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[orange11] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[67Vq8cvCSVm9GROgOY-ifQ][orange11][2]: SearchParseException[[orange11][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"timeout":10000,"query_binary":"eyJzaXplIiA6IDEwLCAiZnJvbSIgOiAwLCAicXVlcnkiIDogeyAibWF0Y2giIDogeyAiX2FsbCIgOiB7InF1ZXJ5IiA6ICJkb2xvcmUifX19LCAiaGlnaGxpZ2h0IiA6IHsiZmllbGRzIiA6IHsgIioiIDoge319LCAicmVxdWlyZV9maWVsZF9tYXRjaCIgOiBmYWxzZX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[orange11] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[67Vq8cvCSVm9GROgOY-ifQ][orange11][3]: SearchParseException[[orange11][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"timeout":10000,"query_binary":"eyJzaXplIiA6IDEwLCAiZnJvbSIgOiAwLCAicXVlcnkiIDogeyAibWF0Y2giIDogeyAiX2FsbCIgOiB7InF1ZXJ5IiA6ICJkb2xvcmUifX19LCAiaGlnaGxpZ2h0IiA6IHsiZmllbGRzIiA6IHsgIioiIDoge319LCAicmVxdWlyZV9maWVsZF9tYXRjaCIgOiBmYWxzZX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[orange11] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[67Vq8cvCSVm9GROgOY-ifQ][orange11][4]: SearchParseException[[orange11][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"timeout":10000,"query_binary":"eyJzaXplIiA6IDEwLCAiZnJvbSIgOiAwLCAicXVlcnkiIDogeyAibWF0Y2giIDogeyAiX2FsbCIgOiB7InF1ZXJ5IiA6ICJkb2xvcmUifX19LCAiaGlnaGxpZ2h0IiA6IHsiZmllbGRzIiA6IHsgIioiIDoge319LCAicmVxdWlyZV9maWVsZF9tYXRjaCIgOiBmYWxzZX19fQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[orange11] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:237)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:183)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Query is:

```
{"size" : 10, "from" : 0, "query" : { "match" : { "_all" : {"query" : "'+searchTerm+'"}}}, "highlight" : {"fields" : { "*" : {}}, "require_field_match" : false}}}
```

The Node Settings are:

```
        ImmutableSettings.Builder meineSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();
    meineSettings.put("node.name", "orange11-node");
    meineSettings.put("path.data", "/Users/lucaarchidiacono/IdeaProjects/moap2/MP3_MoapSampleBuild/data/index");
    meineSettings.put("index.store.type", "memory");
    meineSettings.put("http.enabled", false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decoded query is this one:

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "dolore"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": false
  }
}}
```

You have one too many curly brace at the end, it should be

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "dolore"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": false
  }
}          <--- fix this
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that what a blame from my side.

Comment: No worries, glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In milliseconds, not seconds.

```
GET /_search?timeout=10ms
```

Comment: Note that the timeout is not the issue, the query is not well-formed.